# how to create and process .md pages

Tags: github, markdown

I just saw on github the readme pages are a kind of easy-way to style a simple readme file

Does anyone know where can I get more info on how to convert .md to a real html page?
Is it something specific from github or a sort of gem it is needed?

readme.md

## Title 1

### title 2

**bold text**

[linke_text](http://ble.bla.com) paragraph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various [Markdown](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/markup_processors) gems detailed at the Ruby Toolbox and it is probably best and easiest to use an existing gem.

I have used [Maruku](https://github.com/bhollis/maruku) in the past and it has worked vey well. I believe Github use another gem called [Red Carpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) for Github Pages.

For example with Maruku:

```
doc = Maruku.new('# Title 1')
puts doc.to_html
```

This would output:

```
<h1>Title 1</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

The format you're looking at is Markdown.  Homepage for Markdown is here: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

Markdown is also the markup format that StackOverflow uses.

Answer (score 2):

For instant conversion, you can take a look at http://www.markdown.io/

I.e, if you file is on http://example.com/myfile.md, you just put markdown.io in front of it: `http://markdown.io/http://example.com/myfile.md`